# Linux module for modify packets(Netfilter)

Tags: linux, module, packet

Can anybody tell me how can i modify packet data by linux module using Netfilter hooks?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? (http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried nothing because i cant find something

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to write your own netfilter module. You can to it from userspace using the QUEUE target from iptables, and writing a daemon which processes the queue.

There are relatively few examples of this, but some do exist. It's normally used for filtering, but you can also (I believe) reinject modified packets (at least in the mangle table of iptables).

Comment: Can anyone share any link that show how to use nf_reinject function along with netfilter hook?

Answer (score 2):

Try below program

Write IPTABLES rule to pass packet to user space packet

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p TCP -j QUEUE
```

compile and execute as

```
$ gcc test.c -lipq
$ sudo ./a.out
```

Source code

```
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <linux/netfilter.h> 
#include <libipq.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


#define BUFSIZE 2048
static void die(struct ipq_handle *h)
{
    ipq_perror("passer");
    ipq_destroy_handle(h);
    exit(1);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int status, i=0;
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];
    struct ipq_handle *h;
    h = ipq_create_handle(0, NFPROTO_IPV4);

    if (!h)     die(h);

    status = ipq_set_mode(h, IPQ_COPY_PACKET, BUFSIZE);

    if (status < 0) die(h);

    do{
        i++;
        status = ipq_read(h, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);

        if (status < 0) die(h);

        switch (ipq_message_type(buf)) {
            case NLMSG_ERROR:
                fprintf(stderr, "Received error message %d\n",
                ipq_get_msgerr(buf));
                break;
            case IPQM_PACKET:
            {
                ipq_packet_msg_t *m = ipq_get_packet(buf);
                printf("\nReceived Packet");
                /****YOUR CODE TO MODIFY PACKET GOES HERE****/
                status = ipq_set_verdict(h, m->packet_id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
                if (status < 0)  die(h);
                break;
            }
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown message type!\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (1);
    ipq_destroy_handle(h);
    return 0;
}
```